# android: how to encypt local information and connections?

Tags: java, android, encryption

I,m designing an android app that will have the same functionality of twitter or Instgram. Basically, the app will exchange data with the company servers. I need to ask two questions here. What is the best and most secure way to store critical information since the app package can be reverse engineered? Second, is the public key encryption good for transferring data between the phone and the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public key encryption is fine for transfer.  In fact its the norm, its what https uses.  (Just using https is acceptable).  As for encrypting data locally-  why do you think you need to do that?  The posts will be readable by the owner of the device anyway, what's the actual value in encrypting them on disk?  The only thing I could think of would be to encrypt the username/password, which isn't something you should be storing anyway.

Comment: I need to store the server address and the authentication information between the phone and the server. I'm trying to find a good strategy to make the connection secure. Until now what I'm planning to do is to encrypt this information and store the encryption key in a safe place.

Comment: You're engineering things wrong.  You don't need to encrypt the server address, nor is it advisable-  for one thing all they need to do is look at the router, no matter how much encryption you use.  As for the authentication information-  use a token based system and public key cryptography on the data sent between the server and client (https is enough).  With that there's no need to encrypt the authentication data-  it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: that's really helped me. Thank you so much.

Comment: one last question please, how can i make the sign up operation (register new user) secure?

Comment: Just use https. That encrypts the data. No token needed because they aren't logged in. (It can return a token so account creation logs you in if you want)

Comment: yes i understand that but how can i prevent hackers from overwhelming the server with register operations?

Comment: That's more of a network infrastructure question. Look into how to prevent ddos attacks